# MongoDB aggregation make inner array in root

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-lookup

Hi I have two collection **person** and **department**. Those collection have the properties as below.

I want to aggregate and add a inner array in to the root of the document. Please check the result I need below:

**person:**

```
{
  _id:ObjectID("5ff93b43535bera64de4"),
  first_name: some name,
  last_name : some name,
  dept: department1,

}
```

**department:**

```
{
  dept_name: department1,
  dept_descp : this is description,
  books: [
          {
           book_name: book1,
           subject: subject1,
           },
            {
           book_name: book2,
           subject: subject2,
           },
         ]
}
```

So far I have tried but I didn't get the needed result

```
person.aggregate([
   {
   $match:
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("5ff93b43535bera64de4")
        }
    },
   {
        $lookup: {
            from: "department",
            localField: "dept",
            foreignField: "dept_name",
            as: "ndept"
        }
   },
   {
     $project:{"books": '$ndept.books'}
   }
   ])
```

the result I would like to get is

**Result:**

```
{
  _id:ObjectID("5ff93b43535bera64de4"),
  first_name: some name,
  last_name : some name,
  dept: department1,
  books: [
          {
           book_name: book1,
           subject: subject1,
           },
            {
           book_name: book2,
           subject: subject2,
           }
         ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$arrayElemAt` to select first element from array

```
{
  $addFields: {
    books: { $arrayElemAt: ["$ndept.books", 0] }
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1uUGzHlsfTP)